# Unable to create task for a Case: insufficient privileges

Tags: tasks, owd

Situation: OWD for both Account and Case set to Private. I create an Account, then click New Task. No problem.

Next, I create a Case, click New Task: insufficient priviliges.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Good Morning, I think that your problem is your profile, it has not access to Cases(Create, Edit, Delete....)? Regards

Comment: The user can create, edit, etc. Cases. He is the owner of the Case.

Comment: What you're saying is the problem is with creating Tasks related to Cases, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Do you have a "Contact" field on your task? If so, does the profile have access to Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several possibilities why this is happening.

- If cases are handled by another group of Users, you may have an assignment rule that kicks in and transfers ownership upon creation. Since OWD is private, although you created the Case, you'd no longer have the privilege to create tasks related to it since you'd no longer be the Owner (just as would be the case with Opportunities related to your Account).
- Its possible that your Org on provides Case support when there's an SLA of some kind that exists for the Account or only when the Account has purchased a product. If that's the situation, a new Case for such an Account, while it might get created, it might also not go any further when the SLA isn't found.
- If you no longer own the Case due to an Assignment Rule having fired, your ability to access or do anything related to the Case could, such as creating a Task, would depend on Case Sharing Rules and your CaseTeamRole, assuming you're a CaseTeamMember.

I'm certain there are other possibilities, but these are the 3 that I could think of.

This genuinely sounds like an issue related to Sharing and Roles related to Cases and Assignment Rules. I don't know if new Accounts go through an Approval Process in your Org, and if so, whether that would affect Cases or not. There are a myriad of possibilities.

I suggest you check your work rules, assignment rules, sharing rules, Case Team Membership, Case Team Templates and Case Team Role assignment rules if the latter three are used along with any Service Agreements or Entitlements related to Case support in your Org that you may have in place.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer, I am going to check all this. The org is pretty simple, no workflows, no approval processes, no assignment rules. The Case is owned by the user who tries to create a Task, I have checked that. There are some sharing rules, but they can only add access, not take it away. Also, a Case team is active, but the user trying to create a Task is owner of the Case, not a member of the Case Team. The thing is: the user can create a Task for an Account. Why there, but not for a Case?

Comment: If they still own the Case, that makes no sense to me. There were so many possibilities, I was simply listing the ones I could think of that might apply with Private OWDs, particularly since you said he created the case, but didn't say he was still the owner. Totally agree with you on what sharing rules do in terms of adding access, not restricting it.

Comment: Well, the org in which this occurs is one that we used for a couple of experiments, for a new project. We created a new org, with all the same conditions (as far as we know), and no problems there. So in the old org, something is off. We don't know what, and we are no longer investing any time in it. Unsolved mystery. Unsatisfactory, but such is life. Thanks for your time!